# Lync 2013, Accept incoming InstantMessage call

Tags: c#, lync, lync-2013, lync-client-sdk

Im having some troubles with the Lync 2013 client SDK. I want to accept incoming conversations with my own program. For AV-calls this is working fine: When a new conversation starts, the ConversationAdded event fires, the AVModality state of the conversation is Notified and when calling Accept on the modality, the conversation window of Lync pops up as expected.

The trouble comes when trying to handling incoming IMcalls. On an incoming IMcall, the InstantMessageModality State is connected instead of notified. Also, calling Accept() on the modality does nothing. The first is acceptable, as i can register to window available events and interpret that. The second however, is not. To me it seems rather strange this doesn't work.

Is there any way to accept an incoming IM conversation like a AVconversation? (**Ie, the Lync toast should dissappear and the lync conversation window should open**)

Thnx

Answer (score 0):

Did you already look at [How to: Join a Lync conversation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj937250.aspx) on MSDN? In that doc they explain how joining/accepting an incoming A/V conversation is different than doing the same for an incoming IM conversation.
E.g. one of the differences is that IM conversation does not need to be connected.

HTH

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, the thing is on a new IM-invitation, the small Lync popup is shown, then when you click that one, the 'normal' conversationwindow is shown. I did notice the differences between AV and IM, but that's not problematic. What I'm asking for is a way to (effectivly) "click the small popup" by use of the API, in such a way the Lync conversationwindow pops up.

Comment: I see. That particular need was not really evident to me. Re-reading your question I now pointed more attention when you write *Ie, it should open the lync conversation window*. If I may suggest, you could highlight that that is what you're after