# Simulate a Click on a button with no apparent handle

Tags: c#

I'd like to simulate a mousedown on a button of a window that is not visible (because another window is in front of it). (For those who care/wonder, the reason i want to do this is to bypass behavior of Lync, [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29117015/lync-2013-accept-incoming-instantmessage-call))

I have a decent way of getting the handle of the 'hidden' window and I can also enumerate the controls in that window. However, all those controls have a Handle set to 0, so I can't use `SendMessage` directly...

```
private static void ClickAccept()
{
        var hwnd = Win32.FindWindowsWithText("Toast").FirstOrDefault();

        if (hwnd == IntPtr.Zero)
            return;
        //Get parent window.
        AutomationElement element = AutomationElement.FromHandle(hwnd);
        //Get all descendants
        AutomationElementCollection elements = element.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants, Condition.TrueCondition);
        //loop through descendants
        foreach (AutomationElement elementNode in elements)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("class: " + elementNode.Current.ClassName + ", name: " + elementNode.Current.Name + ", Handle: " + elementNode.Current.NativeWindowHandle);

        }
}
```

Result:

```
class: NetUINativeHWNDHost, name: , Handle: 525312
class: NetUIHWNDElement, name: , Handle: 1050608
class: NetUINetUIDialog, name: , Handle: 0
class: NetUINUILyncElement, name: , Handle: 0
class: NetUINUILyncElement, name: , Handle: 0
class: NetUISimpleButton, name: Accept, Handle: 0
class: NetUIImage, name: , Handle: 0
class: NetUIImage, name: , Handle: 0
class: NetUIAccessibilityAnnouncer, name: , Handle: 0
class: NetUILabel, name: , Handle: 0
class: NetUIImage, name: , Handle: 0
class: NetUIImage, name: , Handle: 0
class: NetUILabel, name: site_110020@askroger.nl, Handle: 0
class: NetUIAccessibilityAnnouncer, name: , Handle: 0
class: NetUILabel, name: sip:lkjdf@lkjd.nl: SITE, Handle: 0
class: NetUIAccessibilityAnnouncer, name: Incoming Skype for Business Toast: site_110020@askroger.nl sip:lkjdf@lkjd.nl: SITE. Press Windows+Shift+O to accept, Windows+Escape to decline., Handle: 0
class: NetUINUILyncElement, name: , Handle: 0
class: NetUINUILyncElement, name: , Handle: 0
class: NetUIAnchor, name: , Handle: 0
class: NetUIButton, name: Options, Handle: 0
class: NetUINUILyncElement, name: , Handle: 0
class: NetUIButton, name: Ignore, Handle: 0
```

I'm guessing it has something to doe with the HWNDHost, but i did not find decent info. How can i simulate a mouseclick on the "Accept" button now?

Comment: If you use the actual EnumWindows API .. do the handles come through?

Comment: You are using automation already! Why would you resort to faking input?

Comment: You're already using the automation classes - why are you not continuing and trying to use *automation* to "click" the button?

Comment: @Simon Whitehead, no i only get the two with handles, thats even why i started with automation.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan and Damien_The_Unbeliever, can you explain how? (or point me in the direction)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747211(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Awesome!         if (elementNode.Current.Name == "Accept")
                {
                    object pattern;
                    if(elementNode.TryGetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern, out pattern))
                    {
                        (pattern as InvokePattern).Invoke();
                    }
                }
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @DavidHeffernan and @Damien_The_Unbeliever
Using automation to click it works!

```
        private static void ClickAccept()
    {
        var hwnd = Win32.FindWindowsWithText("Toast").FirstOrDefault();

        if (hwnd == IntPtr.Zero)
            return;
        //Get parent window.
        AutomationElement element = AutomationElement.FromHandle(hwnd);
        //Get all descendants
        AutomationElementCollection elements = element.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants, Condition.TrueCondition);
        //loop through descendants
        foreach (AutomationElement elementNode in elements)
        {
            if (elementNode.Current.Name == "Accept")
            {
                object pattern;
                if(elementNode.TryGetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern, out pattern))
                {
                    (pattern as InvokePattern).Invoke();
                    return;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```