# VB .NET Automation of selecting options in menu strip of external program

Tags: vb.net, winapi

I am trying to automate an external application using VB .NET. The external application was written in VB .NET and uses win forms. Using Spy++, I can edit text fields and press buttons etc. However, I am unsure how to approach selecting an item from the menu.

At the top of the application is a menu, which also has sub-menus and secondary sub-menus, similar to [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/menustrip). Spy++ regards the whole menu strip as one element and I have no idea how to select an item if I have the handle for the menu strip.

So far I'm just automating the app with:

```
Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As Integer, ByVal hWnd2 As Integer, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Integer
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Integer
Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, lParam As String) As Integer
```

Maybe there is an api for handling menus like this, but I haven't found it.

Hopefully, someone would be able to enlighten me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WinForms, there are two different types of menus. The older MainMenu control implemented native Win32-style menus, the ones you can manipulate with [standard Windows API functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646977.aspx). The newer MenuStrip control was a completely owner-drawn menu bar, written in C# and designed to mimic the appearance of 2000-vintage Microsoft Office applications. Unfortunately, many WinForms applications use the ugly MenuStrip control because it was (A) the default, and (B) made it easier to display images on menu items. Because the MenuStrip is written in C# and has nothing to do with the native Win32 menu implementation, you cannot use standard API functions to interact with it. Spy++ shows it as a single control, effectively a black box.

Most other WinForms controls, though, like buttons and text boxes, are wrappers around the native Win32 controls, so you can see them with Spy++ and interact with them using the standard Windows API functions. (Of course, you should *not* be calling the ANSI versions of these functions, unless you are writing a VB 6 application.)

If you absolutely *must* manipulate the internals of another application, then you should use [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx) to do it. This will work for both real controls and fake controls.

Comment: Thank you. Have looked into UI Automation before and remember to find it confusing. However, looked again into it and am starting to understand a bit more. It is actually the answer I needed - your clear guidance set me on the right track :) For others looking for a coding example, I found this (in C# I think): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29119171/simulate-a-click-on-a-button-with-no-apparent-handle and this is easily adapted to VB.